# assert works in bash for every input I give it even if it's wrong? how to fix this?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I wrote a code using C++ and then wrote a main file to check it, and in this main file I used an assert to check if the values I get are true or not ...
but after a while I discovered I don't get any mistake on bash even though I entered wrong values. Anyone knows why? Or why such a thing happens?

for example :

```
assert(numOfSegments == 1); // i don't get warning 
//but also

assert(numOfSegments == 100); // also here no warning even though this is wrong
```

> //this is how i compile in bash :
>
> g++ -std=c++0x -DNDEBUG -g *.cpp

Comment: This has nothing to do with bash.

Comment: yes .. because i am testing this on bash and the problem is that assert is not working corectly on bash. because for every input bash doesn't give me any warning . i want it to give me any warning

Comment: So, are you saying it is working in another shell? Which one? (Just a rhetorical question. I'm still pretty sure it is not related to bash. Imagine you asked something about cooking and that you burned your food. Would you tag the question as [knife] because you used a knife to cut the food?)

Comment: i am using only bash for now and it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert:

> If `NDEBUG` is defined as a macro name at the point in the source code where  is included, then assert does nothing.

Since you are compiling with `-DNDEBUG`, those statements are not doing anything at all.

Comment: so i should compile without -DNDEBUG ?

Comment: @anna, That is correct.

Comment: do you know what i should add to my compile line so it would not tell me that nullPtr was not declared in this scope ?

Comment: and thank you so much sir :)

Comment: @anna, please create another post regarding `nullPtr`, with a [mcve].

Comment: no it's ok ....